# Schur-Weyl Duality - references

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I'm trying to understand the Schur-Weyl duality. Unfortunately the lecture notes I have don't describe it very detailed. Any good references?

Comment: The book by Fulton and Harris.

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling to find any resources that explicitly even stated the theorem itself, rather than some special case or implication - including the Wikipedia article - until I came across this: 
http://www.win.tue.nl/~jdraisma/teaching/invtheory0910/lecturenotes12.pdf
which gives a bit of an explanation, a statement of the theorem and a proof, starting on p67. Hope this helps.

Also, answers to the seemingly related question [[Schur-Weyl Duality ( Classical ) and the Double Commutant reference request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260378/schur-weyl-duality-classical-and-the-double-commutant-reference-request) ] seem to be helpful.